# Giving meaning to an invalid integral calculation

Tags: calculus, integration

I know that the following calculation is invalid because the integrand is not continuous over the interval $-1 \leq x \leq 1$, but apparently the final result can still be given meaning.
$$\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{dx}{x^{2}} = \left [ -\frac{1}{x} \right ]_{-1}^{1} = -1 - 1 = -2$$

Supposedly a clue lies in the fact that
$$\int_{-\infty }^{-1}\frac{dx}{x^{2}} = \int_{1}^{\infty }\frac{dx}{x^{2}} = 1$$

but I still have no idea what meaning can be gleaned from the result.

Help me out? Thanks (:

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to ask. What is it you want to know?

Comment: I don't know what I want to know. My textbook mysteriously asks 'what meaning can be given to the final result' and then gives that hint in the answer section. (: Do you know what it's looking for?

Comment: Oh I see now. What do you know about the integrand? What fundamental property does it have?

Comment: Even symmetry...? Not sure, sorry...

Comment: Not quite what I was looking for but that is important. Your function is positive. What do you know about the integral of a positive function?

Comment: It's also positive provided (upper bound) > (lower bound)?

Comment: Exactly. So do you see some sort of contradiction?

Comment: I do, yeah, but I don't know what it means. :P

Comment: What it is saying is that if your function has a vertical asymptote, you can't necessarily apply the fundamental theorem of calculus since by blindly applying it in this case, you got a negative area (but your function is always greater than zero).

Answer (score 2):

The integral diverges at $x \sim 0$. What you can work out is the principal part:

\begin{eqnarray*}
{\cal P}\int_{-1}^{1}{{\rm d}x \over x^{2}}
& \equiv &
\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^{+}}\left(%
\int_{-1}^{-\epsilon}{{\rm d}x \over x^{2}}
+
\int_{\epsilon}^{1}{{\rm d}x \over x^{2}}\right)
=
\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^{+}}\left\lbrack%
\left({-1 \over -\epsilon} - {-1 \over -1}\right)
+
\left({-1 \over 1} - {-1 \over \epsilon}\right)
\right\rbrack
\\
& = &
\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^{+}}\left(-2 + {2 \over \epsilon}\right) = \infty
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 0):

The integral gives the area under a curve produced by a continuous curve.
The fact that function has an asymptote at $x=0$ means it isn't continuous and so the integral can't be used to represent the area. This is demonstrated by the fact that you get a negative area even though the order of integration limits ensures it would be positive, and there is obviously non-negative area under the curve when graphed. The meaning is that integration only works for continuous differentiable functions.

Comment: You had the right idea at first but got led astray. The point is that the fundamental theorem of calculus doesn't work for every function.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your result was right. Then,

$$\begin{align*}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{x^2}\ dx &= \int_{-\infty}^{-1} \frac{1}{x^2}\ dx + \int_{-1}^1 \frac{1}{x^2}\ dx + \int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^2}\ dx \\
 &= 1 - 2 + 1 \\
 &= 0.
\end{align*}
$$

But $\frac{1}{x^2}$ is an even function, and the only even function that integrates to zero over the whole real line is $f(x) = 0$.